# Navbar resize issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With bootstrap 3, I created this navbar.

The issue I have is the size. When I resize the screen, I get bad result.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="search-form" name="search-form">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-left:10px;">    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Mumbai <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu multi">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#"><strong>Mumbai</strong></a>

                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-left checkbox" style="margin-right:10px;">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inactiveLodger">Locataire inactif</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like you can see on the picure, when the screen size is big, the size of the bar seem small.

Is there a way to fix that?

I would like to stay with the result of the first image.

[image]

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ro4948pg/)

Comment: Please provide your CSS code or create a JSFiddle to reproduce the error.

Comment: i provided a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Hope it will work for you and resolve the issue**

Replace this

```
<div role="navigation" class="navbar">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
```

with this

```
<div role="navigation" class="navbar">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just removed   `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">` then replace line   `<div class="navbar">` with   `<div class="container">`

**[See the result in JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/faramarzirad/ro4948pg/2/)**